# Render relationship model in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to render a model with a relationship but I am not able to do so.

```
class LogBook(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Nom du registre de maintenance")
        members = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    class LogMessages(models.Model):
        logbook = models.ForeignKey(LogBook)
        message = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Détail du problème")

    class LogDone(models.Model):
        logmessage = models.ForeignKey(LogMessages)
        message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**My view:**

```
log = get_object_or_404(LogBook, pk=log_id)
logmessages = LogMessages.objects.filter(logbook=log_id)
```

My template

```
{% for logmessage in logmessages.all %}
{{logmessage.logdone.message}}
{{% endfor %}}
```

But the logdone object is not showing, any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your LogMessage model has a foreign key to log done, it's not a One to One relation and you have to access the related LogDone objects using the _set notation. There's also a slight typo, I believe. It should `logmessages` and not `logmessages.all`

```
{% for logmessage in logmessages %}
{% for done in logmessage.logdone_set.all %}
    {{ done.message }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I added a related_name equal to "logdones" so I did the following :

```
{% for logmessage in logmessages %}
{% for done in logmessage.logdones.all %}
    {{ done.message }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And now it is working, thanks to @Vishal